# Ref a current Form to the constructor of another Form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, reference

Hello i have newbie question. 
so i have to forms (main window & settings) and i want to pass the main form as a reference to the settings form so i can change variables from there.

i have this constructor in the settings:

```
    public Settings(ref Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }
```

and this is my passing method:

```
    private void TsmiSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings wSettings = new Settings(ref this );
    }
```

but "this" wont work cus its readonly..

any ideas how to solve this? 
or is there another better way to make things work?

Comment: 1st thing,  remove ref in your setting constructor,     public Settings( Form1 form1)
    {
        this.form1 = form1;
    }    if you want it to change.  Second,  you might have to rerender your main form form1 . invalidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the "ref" keyword.
Non-primitive variables are passed by reference and not by value.
Look at: [Non-Primitive Types](https://www.jeremyshanks.com/c-variables-primitive-nonprimitive-types/#crayon-5df4cdcf5cb18494396355)

All you have to do is pass "this" alone like this:

```
Settings wSettings = new Settings(this);
```

And on the Settings side the constructor should look something like this:

```
public class Settings
{
    private Form1 _form;

    public Settings(Form1 form)
    {
        this._form = form;
    }
}
```